# Facing issue in upgrading tcl version

Tags: linux, tcl

I am trying to upgrade TCL 8.6.1 to 8.6.8. does anyone knows what are the packages need to pick and what is the process to carry out.?

Comment: **Tcl-8.6.8** is the default `tcl` in new OS´ : E.g. Fedora 28, Ubuntu 18.04! Version 8.6.1 is **5** years old. .... Please edit your question to include required information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask → OS name and version.

Comment: Which distribution? Which version of that distribution?